# How to save a binary after patching it in cheat engine?

Tags: patching, cheat-engine

The title asks it all tho
But cheat engine will not allow you to save the patch binary so
what methods can I try to save it after I patch it in cheat engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not entirely sure how you would use Cheat Engine to do that but I have done that quite a bit using Immunity/WinDbg. What you do is patch the portion you’re interested in and then apply the changes and write to a new exe.

If this is something you see yourself doing quite a bit, you can program it and do it that way. If you end up going that route, you can use [pefile](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile) with Python or put a little bit more work in and do it in C/CPP.